# How to recover 3 year chat history on Skype

Tags: skype

My Skype history is set to retain history for ever. Now I have a very important reason to view my chat with a friend that took place 3 years past. Is this post to retrieve? Currently I am only able to see maximum of 1 year old message even thought the setting is set to save chat forever.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a copy of the `main.db` file, then you can see the old chat history.

> 1. Hold down the Windows key on your keyboard, then press R to bring up the Run window. ...
> 2. Type `%appdata%\Skype` into the Run window and press Enter.
> 3. Open the folder named after your Skype Name.
> 4. Find the `main.db` file in the folder, this file is your chat history.

---

Other thing you can download this free application – [SkypeLogView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/skype_log_view.html)

With `SkypeLogView` you can open `main.db` file and see which chat and call data are available there.

Answer (score -1):

[SkyHistory](https://skyhistory.scand.com/new-release/) new feature will save your chat history in cloud storages in main.db file

Comment: Are you affiliated to it or was it just a random software recommendation?