# How can I recover a deleted Skype conversation?

Tags: skype

I deleted a Skype conversation by mistake. I don't see any options in the interface to recover it. How can I recover a deleted conversation/chat in Skype?

Comment: Which version of Skype are you using? Does it not reappear if you double-click the person you were chatting with?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
Delete option is only on mobile version. And looks like it just delete history/

Comment: Can you explain more to improve your answer in order to help other users with the same problem

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  However, this doesn't really explain how to recover it.  Can you elaborate?  Thanks.

Comment: yass, @fixer123, you don't need to recover chat conversation, since it doesn't delete. "Delete" option is available only in mobile phone, and looks like it just clear a history for this chat. To recover messages it are many answered questions:   https://superuser.com/questions/977927/how-to-recover-3-year-chat-history-on-skype